# Flutter app won't runs on iOS device after closing

Tags: flutter

Application runs well when I start it from VC, but when I close it(remove from memory) and try start from phone it blinks with white bg for a second and disappear. On Android devices and iOS simulator it works well. What problem it can be?

Here my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:prometey_app/models/auth_model.dart';
import 'package:prometey_app/screens/auth/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:prometey_app/screens/main/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:prometey_app/theme.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'controllers/data_manager.dart';

bool isLoggedIn = false;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await DB.init();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    DB.getUser().then((user) {
      print("Get user data from sqlite");
      if (user != null) {
        print("Try to login with local data");
        bitrixAuth(user.email, user.password).then((userResponse) {
          if (userResponse.success) {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            print("Login success");
            runApp(MyApp());
          } else {
            print("Auth data changed");
            isLoggedIn = false;
            runApp(MyApp());
          }
        });
      } else {
        print("No user records in sqlite");
        isLoggedIn = false;
        runApp(MyApp());
      }
    });
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Прометей',
          theme: _theme(),
          home: isLoggedIn ? MainScreen() : AuthScreen()),
    );
  }

  ThemeData _theme() {
    return ThemeData(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Global.bgColor,
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        disabledColor: Global.bgAccent,
        buttonColor: Global.bgAccent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.normal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you run an app in `debug` mode, app won't be launched after closing. You need to launch an app in `profile` or `release` mode for use it after close. Read more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14#launching-debug-flutter-without-a-host-computer).

Comment: Ah thanks! I was struggling with this for more than 2 hours!